# Storage / Access solutions for web apps. localStorage + db in memory?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two separate needs in my javascript web app:

1. storing data on the client to reduce server requests, and
2. querying the data in complex ways.

I'm struggling to understand the various browser compatibilities.  Is the best widely-compatible solution to store my data in localStorage as strings (problem 1) and then read it into some in-memory database like [TaffyDB](http://taffydb.com/) (problem 2)?

Is there any javascript database that stores itself in localStorage for me?

Ideally I wouldn't have to load the whole thing into the database just to run a query that would return a subset of the data.  When I'm looking for 4 records out of 1000, it might be just as fast to query the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for a list of cross-browser storage options.